# Returning a reference to an implicitly constructed parameter vs an implicitly constructed internal object

Tags: c++, c++11

C++11 question

Trying to understand an issue I came across in our code.  Not looking for the "right" way to do this, just want to know how this is supposed to work so I can figure out how to fix things in the future

I think function `f1()` is fine returning a reference to the temp implicitly constructed on the same line as the `p1`

But what about `p2`?  The temp is constructed implicitly in the body of `f2()` when calling `f1()`, but `f2()` is returning the reference that is being returned by `f1()`.  I thought the lifetime of the temp is extended to match the lifetime of the reference

asking because in one of our compilers `p2` is garbage on the next time, but on the others it is not

```
struct PP
{
    int i;
    PP(int i_) : i(i_) {}
};


const PP &f1(const PP &p) 
{
 return p; 
}

const PP &f2(int i) 
{
 return f1(i); 
} // does the temp live here after return?

int main()
{
    const PP &p1 = f1(1);
    const PP &p2 = f2(2);  // is p2 valid on the NEXT line
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Throw some temporary debug-prints into the constructor and destructor of your PP class, and into main(), and you’ll get a log on stdout showing when each object is created and destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is undefined behaviour, and the fact that different compilers have different outputs would suggest that.

In `f2`, you're returning a reference constructed by `f1`, which itself has a reference to the local object `i`. At the end of the scope, `i` dissapears and invalidates the reference.

In fact `clang-tidy` detects this [godbolt example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:23,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:23,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:23,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:23),source:%27struct+PP%0A%7B%0A++++int+i%3B%0A++++PP(int+i_)+:+i(i_)+%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Aconst+PP+%26f1(const+PP+%26p)+%0A%7B%0A+return+p%3B+%0A%7D%0A%0Aconst+PP+%26f2(int+i)+%0A%7B%0A+return+f1(i)%3B+%0A%7D+//+does+the+temp+live+here+after+return%3F%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++const+PP+%26p1+%3D+f1(1)%3B%0A++++const+PP+%26p2+%3D+f2(2)%3B++//+is+p2+valid+on+the+NEXT+line%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:58.32195140734734,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:gsnapshot,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Wextra%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.331155972278154,l:%274%27,m:34.92897450865927,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:31.7376921580074,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:tool,i:(args:%27%27,argsPanelShow:%271%27,compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,stdin:%27%27,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,toolId:clangtidytrunk,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27clang-tidy+(trunk)+%231+with+x86-64+gcc+(trunk)%27,t:%270%27)),l:%274%27,m:33.33333333333333,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:41.678048592652644,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Also in [reference initialization of cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization#Lifetime_of_a_temporary) it states, as an exception to lifetime extension:

> a temporary bound to a return value of a function in a return
> statement is not extended: it is destroyed immediately at the end of
> the return expression. Such return statement always returns a dangling
> reference.

Comment: thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for.  Couldnt find a special case for return values

Comment: If I understand this correctly yes, if p2 received something valid. Which isn't the case here.

Comment: @ShadowMitia sorry, I re-read it again and deleted my obviously wrong comment. Lifetime extension through const won’t apply here.